# Пробелы и табы в Atom

Tags: atom, tab

В редакторе Atom при нажатии на Tab в одном файле отображаются пробелы, в другом табы. Как настроить, чтобы было что-то одно....? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [How to change indentation mode in Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608160/how-to-change-indentation-mode-in-atom)  и [Tabs to Spaces](https://atom.io/packages/tabs-to-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно достаточно в настройках убрать флажок "Soft Tabs" и параметр "Tab Type" поставить в "hard". Это позволит ставить табы везде, где нужно.

Однако иногда этого не достаточно. Если у вас такой случай, попробуйте специальное расширение: https://atom.io/packages/force-tab